# Undefined reference to main - collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, gcc, reference

I'm trying to compile a program (called es3), but, when I write from terminal:

`gcc es3.c -o es3`

it appears this message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could I do?

Comment: Might be a good idea to post the code causing this error.

Comment: @BrandoSK: When I follow that link, I get a 45-second countdown.  Either post the code as part of your question, or narrow it down to a small example that illustrates the problem and post that.

Comment: Ok, I just downloaded your source file.  (1) It's called `es3_f3.c`, not `es3.c`.  (2) It contains multiple errors, for example a missing semicolon on line 18.  It could not possibly have compiled, which means you couldn't get far enough to see the linker error that you report.  Show us your real code.  (The downloaded source file is 73 lines, which is short enough to post here directly.)

Comment: The error message you show is very similar to the one I get when I use the command `gcc es3.c -o es3` with a source file that doesn't define a `main` function.  Whatever source file you're really compiling doesn't define a `main` function.

Comment: Perhaps you screwed your compiler installation, or you want some [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). Check also your [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)

Comment: "(...) which means you couldn't get far enough to see the linker error that you report. Show us your real code." -- Why are you hiding your code?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It means that `es3.c` does not define a `main` function, and you are attempting to create an executable out of it. An executable needs to have an entry point, thereby the linker complains.

To compile only to an object file, use the `-c` option:

```
gcc es3.c -c
gcc es3.o main.c -o es3
```

The above compiles `es3.c` to an object file, then compiles a file `main.c` that would contain the `main` function, and the linker merges `es3.o` and `main.o` into an executable called `es3`.

Comment: the problem is that I put the main function inside my program.. I don't understand why It says that there's no main function... :/

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps your `main` function has been commented out because of e.g. preprocessing.
To learn what preprocessing is doing, try `gcc -C -E es3.c > es3.i` then look with an editor into the generated file es3.i (and search `main` inside it).

First, you should always (since you are a newbie) compile with

```
  gcc -Wall -g -c es3.c
  gcc -Wall -g es3.o -o es3
```

The `-Wall` flag is extremely important, and you should always use it. It tells the compiler to give you (almost) all warnings. And you should always listen to the warnings, i.e. correct your source code file `es3.C` till you got no more warnings.

The `-g` flag is important also, because it asks `gcc` to put debugging information in the object file and the executable. Then you are able to use a debugger (like `gdb`) to debug your program.

To get the list of symbols in an object file or an executable, you can use `nm`.

Of course, I'm assuming you use a GNU/Linux system (and I invite you to use GNU/Linux if you don't use it already).

Comment: yes i'm using Ubuntu! I'll go and try what you're saying thanks..!

Answer (score 14):

In my case it was just because I had not Saved the source file and was trying to compile a empty file .

Comment: in my case i opened file earlier from one directory into gedit and than move it to another directory and try to compile from new directory that i recently moved. but file is empty because it already open.

Comment: me too, write a lot of code and don't save, what a dumb haha

Answer (score 8):

Executable file needs a main function. See below hello world demo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

As you can see there is a main function. if you don't have this main function, ld will report "undefined reference to main' "

check my result:

```
$ cat es3.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -Wall -g -c es3.c
$ gcc -Wall -g es3.o -o es3
~$ ./es3
Hello world!
```

please use `$ objdump -t es3.o` to check if there is a main symbol. Below is my result.

```
$ objdump -t es3.o

es3.o:     file format elf32-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 es3.c
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  00000000 .debug_abbrev
00000000 l    d  .debug_info    00000000 .debug_info
00000000 l    d  .debug_line    00000000 .debug_line
00000000 l    d  .rodata        00000000 .rodata
00000000 l    d  .debug_frame   00000000 .debug_frame
00000000 l    d  .debug_loc     00000000 .debug_loc
00000000 l    d  .debug_pubnames        00000000 .debug_pubnames
00000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 00000000 .debug_aranges
00000000 l    d  .debug_str     00000000 .debug_str
00000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        00000000 .note.GNU-stack
00000000 l    d  .comment       00000000 .comment
00000000 g     F .text  0000002b main
00000000         *UND*  00000000 puts
```

Comment: thank for your answers, but I have the main function inside my program :(

don't understand why the compiler doesn't read it :(

Comment: I have verified on my linux, please check it.

Comment: I believe you don't really have a main; it is obscured, skipped by the preprocessor, made internal or static... Try to `indent` your file, it will be more readable to you...

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I have a main. But I think BrandoSK don't have the main function. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I was speaking to the original poster, BrandoSK. When the compiler says no `main`, he should trust the compiler!!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Couldn't it be that the object file from different architecture and he is trying to make exe of that on different , i am having this problem too

Answer (score 4):

One possibility which has not been mentioned so far is that you might not be editing the file you think you are. i.e. your editor might have a different cwd than you had in mind.

Run 'more' on the file you're compiling to double check that it does indeed have the contents you hope it does. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a `main` function to resolve this problem.
Just like:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The O.P. has a `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

I my case I found out the `void` for the main function declaration was missing.

I was previously using Visual Studio in Windows and this was never a problem, so I thought I might leave it out now too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with NS3, and C++ files are saved with the `.cc` file extension. I saved the file as `.cpp` the common way.

It was as simple as that but took me a while to recognize it.