# Am trying to run the below code but display "(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'" error what is the problem?

Tags: c, terminal, hashtable, computer-science, display

#include "hash_tables.h"

/**

- hash_table_create -> create hash table
- @size: sixe of the hash table
- Return: the new hash table
  */
  hash_table_t *hash_table_create(unsigned long int size)
  {
  hash_table_t *HashTable;

  ```
   HashTable = malloc(sizeof(hash_table_t));                                                                                                             
   if (HashTable == NULL)                                                                                                                                
           return (NULL);                                                                                                                                

   HashTable->size = size;                                                                                                                               
   /*allocating memory for array*/                                                                                                                       
   HashTable->array = malloc(sizeof(hash_node_t *) * size);                                                                                              
   if (HashTable->array == NULL)                                                                                                                         
   {                                                                                                                                                     
           free(HashTable->array);                                                                                                                       
           return (NULL);                                                                                                                                
   }                                                                                                                                                     
   return (HashTable);
  ```

}

Comment: Do you have a `main` function? If so, please post it, if not, then the error message is complaining that you need one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you show the whole error, or just a part of it. From what I tried on ideone.com, when you try to compile code without any `main` function's definition, you receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

See https://ideone.com/qNVMAk

The compilation goes fine if you add a `main` function's definition, for example that one:

```c
int main (void) {
    return 0;
}
```

So, I guess you need to add some `main` function's definition to the code you try to compile.

For details, you can see this similar question: [Undefined reference to main - collect2: ld returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965437/undefined-reference-to-main-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status)